# How to change a style when GridSplitter is focused in Silverlight 4

Tags: c#, silverlight, styles, visualstatemanager, gridsplitter

I have a Silverlight 4 Page.

The page contains a single grid, with three columns. In the middle column, I have put the GridSplitter.

By default it is blue.
I can set its color using its Foreground property.
However, when I drag (focus) the grid splitter, it changes its appearance to another color (some blueish color).

I'd like to define a style for the grid splitter which is applied when the splitter is focused, and another style when it's not.

I have read something about setting the VisualState manager, but I am not sure how to utilize it in this scenario.
I've thought of using the triggers, but it seems that SL does not support them like the WPF does.

How would I change the style depending on the focus state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [following article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278070%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) shows the default style and template for the GridSplitter control.
You can modify  this style as you needed.